# Cmdlet to list all instances of System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher

Tags: powershell

If have have a function that creates a process watcher for a named process, something like this

```
function New-Watcher {
    param ([string] $processname)

    $alarm = New-Object System.Management.EventQuery
    $alarm.QueryString = "Select * from __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE targetinstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND targetinstance.name = '$processname'"
    New-Object System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher $alarm
}
```

and I create mutiple watchers like this

```
$mywatcher1 = New-Watcher "notepad.exe"
$mywatcher2 = New-Watcher "cmd.exe"
# all the way down to...
$mywatcherxxx = New-Watcher "powershell.exe"
```

is there a cmdlet that lists all the instances that have been created ?

Something along the lines of Get-EventSubscriber that works for Register-WmiEvent.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this `Get-Variable | ?{$_.Value -is [System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher]}` which would return an array with `$mywatcher1,2,xxx`....

Comment: @Matt Looks like you got a comment in saying pretty much the same thing as I was while I was typing up an answer. See? I don't always beat you to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are assigning each to a variable you can always do something like:

```
Get-Variable|Where{$_.Value -is [System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher]}
```

That would output:

```
Name                           Value                                                                
----                           -----                                                                
mywatcher1                     System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher                             
mywatcher2                     System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher
```

Or if you wanted to make it nicer you could run the data through a ForEach and make custom objects parsing out what each is watching like this:

```
Get-Variable mywatch*|
    Where{$_.Value -is [System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher]}|
        ForEach{
            $QString = $_.value.query.querystring
            [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                Variable=$_.Name
                Watching=$Qstring.substring(($QString.lastindexof("= "))+2).trim("'")
            }
        }
```

Which would in turn kick back:

```
Variable                                           Watching                                         
--------                                           --------                                         
mywatcher1                                         notepad.exe                                      
mywatcher2                                         cmd.exe
```